# Resetting the id in table without dropping it

Tags: sql, primary-key

There are ten entries in the table and primary key id is set to autoincrement. If I delete all entries and insert one more its id will be 11, is it possible to reset ids to 1 again?

Comment: Microsoft SQLServer 2008

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try truncate table command like below :

```
TRUNCATE TABLE tablename
```

it will reset auto increment id to 1.

If your table is refrenced with other table using foreign key then you can enable/disable contraint using below commands :

To Enable constraint:

```
EXEC sp_msforeachtable @command1="print '?'", 
                       @command2="ALTER TABLE ? WITH CHECK CHECK CONSTRAINT all";
```

To Disable constraint:

```
EXEC sp_msforeachtable "ALTER TABLE ? NOCHECK CONSTRAINT all";
```

Comment: TRUNCATE resets the seed value of identity columns to the seed value defined for the column. The default seed is 1. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177570.aspx

Comment: That implies that you've set up dependencies between your (to-be truncated) table and another one.

Answer (score 1):

DBCC CHECKIDENT("table", RESEED, 1);

You can read more at msdn, [DBCC CHECKIDENT (Transact-SQL)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176057.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

```
ALTER TABLE table AUTO_INCREMENT = 1;
```

You can set any value for "1"